# input validation in loop

Tags: c++, loops, validation

I'm trying to make a validation loop in C++ that checks the user's input until they enter a number between 0 and 100 and however my loop only checks the first condition. Any guidance is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int max_num = 100;
    const int min_num = 0;
    int num;

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    do {
        if (!(cin >> num)) 
        {
            cout << "ERROR:The value provided was not a number" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1024, '\n');

            cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
            cin >> num;
        }
        else if (num<min_num || num>max_num)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: value out of range" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1024, '\n');

            cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
            cin >> num;

        }
    } while (!(cin >> num) || (num<min_num || num>max_num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now would be an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger to run your program one line at a time and observe its logical execution, and how all variables change as the program runs. This is a very simple logical bug, that should be very easy to observe in a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is required skill for every C++ developer. Good luck.

Comment: You have three `(cin >> num)`s in your code, two of which are inside the loop. That seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Add lots of logging to your code so that you know what it's doing. This will help you find the problem. For example, instead of:

```
cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
cin >> num;
```

Try:

```
cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 100" << endl;
cerr << "About to read into num outside the loop" << endl;
cin >> num;
cerr << "Read into num outside the loop, got: " << num << endl;
```

And so on, throughout your code. This should give you enough information to find the bug. Alternatively, use a debugger with a single step function to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in the part of while:

instead of

```
while (!(cin >> num) || (num<min_num || num>max_num));
```

this:

```
while (!cin || (num<min_num || num>max_num));
```

the same for the upper if

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> num` means putting user input to the variable `num` . So you are trying to take user inputs 2 times in the loop. Maybe the check condition: `(num == (int)num)`will solve your problem. It will try to verify the number you have stored in `num` is really of the type `int`